# In $\Delta ABC$, $A-B=60$ and $64\Delta^2=3abc(a+b+c)$, then find $\cos C$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

> Here $\Delta$ is area of triangles, $a$ is side opposite to angle $A$ and so on

$$64 \frac{a^2b^2c^2}{16R^2}=3abc(a+b+c)$$

$$16\sin A\sin B\sin C =3(\sin A +\sin B+\sin C)$$

$$8(\cos (60)+\cos C)\sin C=3(2\cos \frac C2 ( \frac{\sqrt 3}{2})+\sin C)$$

$$8\sin C(\frac 12 +\cos C )=3(\sqrt 3 \cos \frac C2 +\sin C)$$

$$4\sin C (1+2\cos C)=3(\sqrt 3 \cos \frac C2 +\sin C)$$

$$4\sin C (4\cos ^2 \frac C2 -1)=3(\sqrt 3 \cos \frac C2 +\sin C)$$

$$8\sin \frac C2 (4\cos ^2 \frac C2 -1)=3(\sqrt 3 +2\sin \frac C2)$$

$$8(4-4\sin^2\frac C2 -1 )\sin \frac C2 =3(\sqrt 3 +2\sin \frac C2)$$

Solving the cubic

$$\sin \frac C2 =-\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$$

So $\cos C =-\frac 12$

The given answer is $\frac 58$, but I don’t know what went wrong in my computation

Also I would like to avoid a cubic polynomial, since I used a calculator to solve this one.

Thanks

Comment: @g.kov I don’t understand, which third equation are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, misread brace. I rechecked all 8 equations,
they all are fine. 

So for $t=\sin \tfrac C2$ you get a cubic 

$32t^3-18t+3\sqrt3=(2t+\sqrt3)(4t-\sqrt3)^2$.

You just choose the wrong root: $\sin \tfrac C2$ is never negative 
for angles of triangle. 

The other one, $\sin\tfrac12C=\tfrac{\sqrt3}4$ is correct.

Comment: @g.kov I just plugged the equation in wolfram and that's the only solution I got, so I figured the rest were complex. I did realize that the root shouldn't be negative, but I just went with it

Comment: Strange, I've got [both roots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%2832*t%5E3-18*t%2B3*sqrt%283%29%3D0%2Ct%29%3B).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continue with
$$16\sin A \sin B \sin C= 3(\sin A+ \sin B +\sin C)$$

and simplify with $\sin A+ \sin B +\sin C= 4\cos\frac A2\cos\frac B2 \cos\frac C2$
$$32\sin\frac A2\sin\frac B2 \sin\frac C2=3 $$
or 
$$ 16 \left( \cos\frac{A-B}2-\sin\frac C2\right)\sin \frac C2=3 $$

which, with $A-B =60$, yields $\sin\frac C2=\frac{\sqrt3}4 $ and

$$\cos C = 1- 2\sin^2 \frac C2= \frac 58$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align} 
\text{In $\triangle ABC$, if }\quad
A-B&=60^\circ
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
64\Delta^2
&=3abc(a+b+c)
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
\text{find }\cos C.
\end{align}

Equation \eqref{2} in terms of semi-perimeter $\rho$,
inradius $r$ and circumradius $R$ is

\begin{align} 
64(\rho r)^2
&=3\cdot4\rho r R\cdot (2\rho)
=24\rho^2 r R
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
64 r&=24 R
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
\frac rR
&=\frac{24}{64}=\frac38
\tag{5}\label{5}
.
\end{align}

Pairing \eqref{1} with $A+B+C=180^\circ$,
we have

\begin{align} 
A &= 120^\circ-\tfrac12\,C
,\quad
B = 60^\circ-\tfrac12\,C
\tag{6}\label{6}
.
\end{align}

Recall that for the angles of triangle
\begin{align} 
\cos A+\cos B+\cos C&=\frac rR+1
\tag{7}\label{7}
,\\
\text{so }\quad
\cos(120^\circ-\tfrac12\,C)+
\cos(60^\circ-\tfrac12\,C)+
\cos C
-\frac rR-1
&=0
\tag{8}\label{8}
,
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
\cos C+\sqrt3\sin\tfrac12C-\frac{11}8
&=0
\tag{9}\label{9}
,\\
\sin^2\tfrac12C
-\tfrac{\sqrt3}2\, \sin\tfrac12C
+\tfrac3{16}
=(\sin\tfrac12C-\tfrac{\sqrt3}4)^2
&=0
\tag{10}\label{10}
,\\
\sin\tfrac12C
&=\tfrac{\sqrt3}4
\tag{11}\label{11}
,\\
\cos C
=1-2\sin^2\tfrac12C
&=1-2\cdot(\tfrac{\sqrt3}4)^2
=\tfrac58
\tag{12}\label{12}
,
\end{align}

so the given answer is correct.